# Paypal Integration PHP (Pay without a Paypal Account)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a PayPal Checkout in my website (sandbox site testing) and there are 2 options:

> (i) user logins to PayPal and pay 
>   (ii) user creates a PayPal account and then pays

I have seen in many websites that in addition to these 2 options above, a user can even pay directly from his/her credit card without having to register a PayPal account.

> Is it possible to add the Direct Credit Card Payment Option? If yes, can someone list the steps?

Thanks.  I have also attached a photo of my checkout.
[here is the photo of my checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbXwO.png)

Comment: u have to fill all the required field  for paypal form then u have to redirect the url which is given by u r paypal account u have too set secrete key, salt,merchant id all necessary field. then u will direct to paypal page in which there is option of debit credit card

Comment: hey @riya thanks for the reply, can you do it for me? Facebook name: James Ndiaye (keshav)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Paypal Plus https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-plus

But you will have to register to this and they will check if you fulfill the requirements.

You would then also be able to accept other payment types.

Comment: The process of validation might take up to 1 month. However you might be able to still be able to use it while you are in validation.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply, can you do it for me? Facebook name: James Ndiaye (keshav)

Comment: Do what for you? Validate it? You have to register yourself, no one but you can do this for you. You have to give a lot of information about your company and concept.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "guest checkout" and the best way to get it working is to use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

Express Checkout consists of 3 API calls

- SetExpressCheckout
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails
- DoExpressCheckoutPayment

The first call is where you'll include some specific parameters to enable guest checkout by default:

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

You'll need to make sure you're using API Version 109.0 or higher in order for this to work correctly.

One thing to keep in mind, too, is that PayPal is split testing the checkout pages you see when you're sent over to PayPal for payment, so while guest checkout will be available, it may look different each time you go through a test.

Sometimes it will show the full credit card form by default, other times it will just show a button that says "Pay with a Debit or Credit Card" under the login option.

In either case it will be much more prominent than a standard PayPal button.

Another option would be to use Payments Pro or the REST API for direct credit card processing.  In this case you would give people the PayPal or Credit Card option directly on your site.  If they choose PayPal they would go there and login as expected.  If they choose credit card they would never be sent to PayPal at all.  They would simply enter card details directly on your site and they wouldn't know PayPal was involved at all.

Keep in mind that if you end up processing cards directly you'll need an SSL certificate installed on the site and you'll also need to make sure you are never saving any sensitive details (card number, exp. date, cvv code, etc.) to your database, log files, or anywhere on your server.

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls very quick and easy for you.